# System Notification or any Delegate method for power button clicked - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

Currently I am working on a project where the app needs to catch the notification for power button click and send a message or something else to a specified address (may be a phone no). I have no idea is there any notification or something to catch the action of power button click. 
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no way of capturing specifically the press of that button.

You get a notification when your app is backgrounded, but it can be backgrounded for other reasons, like the user pressing Home.

Comment: Also doing that is against the HIG and will get the app rejected 99%. "Using hardware buttons for other function other than what they were intended for is not allowed."